# After clicking on an internal link in a PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, links, navigation

After clicking on a internal link  in an PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Examples of internal link  in a [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03274.pdf) (green rectangles):

[image: link]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 20.12.20041.394260.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the "Previous View" and "Next View" toolbuttons, which you can place in your toolbar. Your Acrobat (Reader) will also tell you the keyboard shortcut. (FWIW, on my Mac, it is Cmd-Cursor left and Cmd-Cursor right).

Note, however, that this sometimes gets confused, especially if you have the "Open Cross-document links in same window" Preference set, and in general if your links are cross-document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can use the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to go back to the location of the text where the internal link is located after clicking on it.